# How do I call a function inside of another function using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, filter, html-table

I'm currently building a search bar (textbox) that compares the input value to the data within a table. The function iterates through the rows of  and hides whichever one doesn't have a name = to input value, or the search string. The filtering section of the code or "Function searchFilter()" doesn't seem to be called properly but I know the code within the function itself works. The code works if I inserted it where it's called. However if I inserted it into its own funciton and call it, it doesn't work. I may be overlooking something, like a parameter issue?

```
function search() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("gvData");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                filterSearch();
            }
        }
    }
    function filterSearch() {
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use `tr[i].style.display = txtValue.toUpperCase().includes(filter) ? "" : "none";`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass all the local variables from the `search` function that are needed by the `filterSearch` function as arguments:

```js
function search() {
    // ...
    filterSearch(tr[i], txtValue, filter);
    // ...
}
function filterSearch(row, txtValue, filter) {
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        row.style.display = "";
    } else {
        row.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really see the point of defining this function when it's only used once and has an extremely narrow scope, though.

Comment: I plan on using it for searching through more options, I just haven't added them as I don't want to expand it until it's working properly.